# Local fields missing in micrometer.tracing as compared to sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer-tracing

I'm migrating a project form Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.1 and one of the steps is migrating sleuth to micrometer.tracing. In sleuth there was this property: `sleuth.baggage.local-fields` used to denote local fields in baggage, but I don't see an equivalent in micrometer.tracing. I found the following properties:

```
management.tracing.baggage.remote-fields
management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields
```

and I don't see an equivalent for `.local-properties`, i looked into TracingProperties and it looks like there is nothing like that.

How can I achieve this functionality in micrometer.tracing?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 3.0 and 3.1 currently it's not supported out of the box.

Comment: Is there a timetable for this feature? Is it planned at all?

Comment: Please check this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33991